# nginx 500 error instead of 404

Tags: nginx

I have the following nginx configuration (at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`)

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Instead of a 404 error, I'm getting 500 server errors on broken urls.  How can I correct this?

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here and hope someone will find it useful: http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMainModule#error_log

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is most likely due to the way the `location /` block works. Please change it as follows...

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: When I changed that line, I no longer see a 500 error at broken URL's.  However, I'm seeing my index.php page instead of 404.html.

Comment: I am updating my answer now to display 404.html for broken URLs correctly. Thanks.